# MySQL+PHP array_count_values

Tags: php, arrays

I need to find the most common value (not 0) from arrays. 
My code:

```
   include ("db.php");
   $query = "SELECT poll1 FROM names";
   $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
       echo  $row['poll1'];
    }
```

And echo results (minimum value 0 (default) and maximum 3):

```
1
1
0
0
0
2
3
```

The most common value is "1". I cant use [array_count_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), because there are 7 arrays of numbers.

Comment: By the way, don't you know `mysql_**` functions are **deprecated**? You'd better use `PDO` instead.

Comment: There are easy ways to do it in PHP by flattening the array, but the _proper_ way to handle this would be to use a `COUNT()` aggregate:  `SELECT poll1, COUNT(*) AS count FROM names GROUP BY poll1`

Comment: What do you mean by *And echo results (minimum value 0 (default) and maximum 3):*? Are you actually trying to find the value that's repeated most, or something else?

Comment: Please try with this query 
SELECT poll1, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM names WHERE poll1 BETWEEN 1 AND 3 GROUP BY poll1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem you should solve with SQL.

Firstly, you want to get the number of people selecting each option:

```
SELECT poll1, COUNT(*) AS count FROM names GROUP BY poll1;
+-------+-------+
| poll1 | count |
+-------+-------+
|     0 |     3 |
|     1 |     2 |
|     2 |     1 |
|     3 |     1 |
+-------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Ok, but you're not interested in zeros, and you only care about the row with the largest value of `count` so you should sort by descending `count`, and limit it to 1 result:

```
SELECT poll1, count(*) AS count FROM names
WHERE poll1 != 0
GROUP BY poll1
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 1;
+-------+-------+
| poll1 | count |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |     2 |
+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Works perfect. Any changes if i'll have 18 of polls in one page? Like poll1, poll2, poll3, ... , poll18